# How to teach git to trust github on linux?

Tags: linux, git, ssl, ssl-certificate

Recently on my linux system i have run into an issue of not being able to commit to my own github repository. When i try to do it, that's what i get:

```
my prompt: > git push --verbose
Pushing to https://github.com/MyUsername/my-repository.git
info: please complete authentication in your browser...
fatal: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
fatal: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
Username for 'https://github.com': 
Password for 'https://github.com': 
remote: No anonymous write access.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/MyUsername/my-repository.git/'
```

What happens is that i get a window that asks me to login to github (through web interface), i do that, get the page "Authorisation successful, return to your application" in my browser - and in my application i can apparently see that my machine does not trust github. For some reason.

How do i persuade it that it is in fact OK to raise secure connection to github?

If that is important, my system is linux mint.

Comment: Don’t use the `https://` URL for any Git repository anywhere. Just use SSH instead. More stable, reliable and that’s how the pros do it.

Comment: Can you post the output of `gnutls-cli github.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For myself, I have had better experiences using SSH for the Git connection than HTTPS.

1. For this you should create a new SSH key, ideally this is protected with a password. The key pair consists of public and private key.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 100 -f ~/.ssh/github
   ```

   - Public key file: `~/.ssh/github.pub`
   - Private key file: `~/.ssh/github`
2. You can now add the public key in the [GitHub Settings](https://github.com/settings/keys) clicking "New SSH key".

   ```
   cat ~/.ssh/github.pub
   ```
3. Afterwards you have to add the new origin to your repository.

   ```
   git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com:MyUsername/my-repository.git
   ```

By using SSH with keys, you no longer have the problem of having to authorize the HTTPS session via the browser. This way you can at least work around your error.

Comment: For practical purposes that worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your root certificate repository.

If you're using a MITM proxy or otherwise have a self-signed or unknown certificate, retrieve the signing certificate and point to it with `sslCAInfo`.